# How to change what controller is to be used by a directive according to a variable?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to be able to provide a different controller for a directive according to a value of a scope variable. been searching along those lines but all the results have been about config of `$route`. So here is a sample:

I want to provide my directive `dir1` with a different controller according to `model.something`'s value.

Code below.

```js
angular.module('mod1', [])
.directive('dir1', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
      model: '='
    },
    controller: function($scope) {
      return control($scope.model.something);
    }
  };
});
function control(param) {
    if(param == 1) return ctrl1;
    else if(param == 2) return ctrl2;
    else return ctrl3;
}
function ctrl1 ($scope,$http) {
    //something1
}
function ctrl2 ($scope,$http) {
    //something2
}
function ctrl3 ($scope,$http) {
    //something3
}
```

need more info??

Comment: I don't think you need to use the $scope. just put a function returning a string or a ternary like controller: a == b ? 'Controller1' : 'Controller2' . It should be auto9matically injected depending of the string your ternary return

Comment: Why would you want different controllers? What is the difference in behaviour you are expecting from each? Perhaps if we had a better understanding of what you are trying to accomplish, there might be a better way.

Comment: @sam but the condition on what controller i will use depends on a scope variable. did i understand what you were saying correctly?

Comment: @deitch I need to have different behavior depending on that scope variable. If else or just different directives would prolly do. Just want to try it this way...?

Comment: The definition of "different behavior" is what matters. Is it something that can be changed based on a scope var?

Comment: yes, most likelly a scope varialbe, or any other value that you can have access from anywhere, like a value stored in a provider or service , or even cookies

Comment: @deitch well for example if `$scope.model.something` == 1 then i need to `$watch` `something` and then do something else if it isn't. Now as I said earlier maybe I really don't need a new controller function. Just if else would be enough... I just thought if I could do it like that. if I won't be using if else, then I wouldn't want to do the `$watch`

Comment: So if it is different views, then, I would go for completely different controllers and templates, or, at most, one template with different controllers determined by the route. But is it necessary to `$watch` different things? Without more concrete example, it is hard to tell, but sounds like you are dealing with one of different routes + different controllers with same template, or different templates + different controllers, or possible different directives?